# How to make sure AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event is always fired?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to use some resolver to handle the resolving failure, I found the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve only works when I use something like
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(***);
but it is refusing to fire when I use something like Assembly.LoadFrom.

How to make sure it is always get fired no matter which way I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty unclear.  But AssemblyResolve will only fire when it *needs* to fire because the CLR cannot find the assembly by itself.  Which is somewhat likely to not be the case when you use LoadFrom() since you normally specify the full path name of the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the AssemblyResolve event is triggered from Activator.CreateInstance.